# ALSA: playing WAV files to specific audio devices gives playback rate errors

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I have several audio sources in my Ubuntu 22.04 setup, including headphones, HDMI monitors, and a [USB audio jack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BZPC4JW5) (connected to oscilloscope). I am trying to play a .WAV file out of the USB audio jack to view it on the oscilloscope.

If I use aplay without any flags, I get the .WAV file playing at my default audio device:

```
aplay stereo_1kHz_sine_1sec.wav
```

If I open up Ubuntu Settings -> Sound -> Output -> Output Device and change the output device to 'AB13X USB Audio', then I see my 1kHz sine wave on the oscope.
Likewise, if I change the output device to my monitor or headphones, I hear the 1kHz tone on that device. So, I know that all of the hardware is working appropriately.

I would like to add flags to my aplay command in order to play the .WAV file without needing to fiddle with the sound settings GUI. My eventual goal is to run some automated audio tests, so I want to use CLI commands that can be scripted. Looking at the [aplay man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/aplay), there is a -D flag for specifying a PCM device to target, so I started using that.

I ran aplay -l to list the available PCM devices:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC897 Analog [ALC897 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 4: Audio [AB13X USB Audio], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

My setup has both integrated graphics and a GPU, so it's not surprising to see so many HDMI options. Through some experimentation, I figured out where my devices are. However, when calling aplay with a specific device targetted, the playback is much higher pitched on both my monitors and my headphones. Additionally, I get warning messages that the rate is not accurate:

```
# Right monitor, recorded as freq 2kHz
$ aplay -D hw:0,3 stereo_1kHz_sine_1sec.wav
Playing WAVE 'stereo_1kHz_sine_1sec.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Stereo
Warning: rate is not accurate (requested = 16000Hz, got = 32000Hz)
         please, try the plug plugin

# Left monitor, recorded as freq 2kHz
$ aplay -D hw:0,8 stereo_1kHz_sine_1sec.wav
Playing WAVE 'stereo_1kHz_sine_1sec.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Stereo
Warning: rate is not accurate (requested = 16000Hz, got = 32000Hz)
         please, try the plug plugin

# Headphones, recorded as freq 2.75kHz
$ aplay -D hw:2,0 stereo_1kHz_sine_1sec.wav
Playing WAVE 'stereo_1kHz_sine_1sec.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Stereo
Warning: rate is not accurate (requested = 16000Hz, got = 44100Hz)
         please, try the plug plugin
```

The difference in recorded frequency lines up with the reported rate error, so nothing odd there. But I am not clear on why aplay is able to play the .WAV file at the correct frequency when used as the default device, but plays an incorrect rate/frequency when the playback device is specified at the command line instead.

I have also had issues with playing mono .WAV files. I can get mono wav files to play with aplay to the default device, and they sound identical to the stereo version. However, the mono version will not play at all when I specify the playback device:

```
$ aplay -D hw:2,0 1kHz_sine_1sec.wav
Playing WAVE '1kHz_sine_1sec.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1358: Channels count non available
```

I have read that you can create config files for ALSA like `$HOME/.asoundrc` or `/etc/asound.conf`. I currently do not have either of these files on my machine. If there is an ALSA config file for the default audio device that is doing some magic behind the scenes, I have not been able to locate it. And I'd prefer not to set up additional config files if possible.

What do I need to do to play my .WAV files to specific audio devices from the command line, without altering the currently selected default audio device?

Will I need to add a new config file to accomplish this?